# Making 2D Games

Tags: c++, java, 2d, software-engineering

I am starting out on making my own games. I am very interested in making 2D side scrolling games, such as SNES/Mega Drive games and eventually I want to create my own Metroid/Cave Story inspired game.

However I don't want to just use a program that will do all the work for me, I want to learn and improve my programming skills as I go along also.

I was wondering if you had any suggestions of how to go about this, I would be really grateful for some answers :)

Also any suggestions on what programming language I should use, would be helpful, as I've been told either C++ or Java

Thank you

James

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. "Where do I start" questions aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A style, and are considered off-topic.

Comment: If you gonna try java give a check on LibGDX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with Java, it's going to be A TON easier than c++. although c++ doesn't have any dependencies, java is better to start out with when creating a game like you've described.

c++ honestly wouldn't be necessary in this case

Comment: Thankyou! Any suggestions of programs as well?

Comment: For programming in Java? Eclipse.

Comment: if your trying to make a simple java game, I would DEFINITELY RECOMMEND eclipse. It's how I started out and it really helped me understand the inner workings of simple game dev. however, you could use different java game engines

Comment: Thaks both of you I'll try out Eclipse.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse should I install, on the download page there are several different ones?

Answer (score 1):

If C# is an alernative ( it is quite similar to Java ) you could check out C#/XNA. It's very easy to make games in it. It helps you with several topics such as intersection, sprites and audio. But you will handle all the logics yourself.

C#/XNA will be easy to start with. Make a few games with it. If you want to handle more of the game engine yourself, you could move on to something different after a while.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, but XNA is turning out to be a pain to install.

Comment: What problem(s) are you facing, @JimmyBunter01? Usually it's a pretty straightforward click&wait installation.

Answer (score 1):

Java is an excellent option to start with given the fact that you can put to good use that experience into creating games for Android if you want to. Besides, it's better to start with Java being strong-typed but developer-friendly when it comes to memory management. The best approach is to learn Java and Java2D. You can load your image files but have to work out [the game loop](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) on your own. After that, you can jump into Android game development.

I'd recommend making a couple old games: breakout, tetris, snake and then work with an API or Framework (like libGDX for Android). Why? Because it's better to [write games than engines](http://scientificninja.com/blog/write-games-not-engines). Unless you're really interested in computer graphics, for example, there is little reason to make a whole complicated game using OpenGL and your language of choice, reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are very new to all of this I strongly recommend using Greenfoot, it is an environment for learning Java by making games. They have many tutorials and will ease you into Java and Game development.

http://www.greenfoot.org/door